# How can i pass params in url like a path in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom

How can I get the params from the URL path as we do in Django?
For example if the url is `domain.dom/userid`,
then we need userid as a param in js and redirect to `domain.dom`.
Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: location.pathname - is that what you mean?

Comment: it will return the path of the current URL but won't redirect to the desired page like index.html or any other page, like if we go to the above mentioned url then it will return   object not found rather than the path name. @mplungjan

Comment: It is completely unclear what you want to achieve. Please elaborate what your expected behaviour is with relevant and detailed input and expected output. Do you mean `location.replace("someurl")`

Comment: I want the user to go to the URL: `domain.dom/userid` I want it to go to `domain.dom/index.html` with the parameter userid

Comment: @NishantSinghal do you mean something like : https://github.com/rcs/route-parser ?

Comment: yes @jmunsch but isn't it possible with js only??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let url =  new URL("https://domain.dom/freddy_user"); // new Url(location.href) 
const userid = url.pathname.slice(1);
url.pathname="index.html";
url.searchParams.set("userid",userid)
console.log(url); // location.replace(url)
```

Comment: on which page should i write this code so that object not found error is not shown

Comment: You put this in the head of the page that receives the userid- you uncomment my comments and remove the test strings

Comment: but it doesn't recieve the request with the error object not found

Comment: I have no idea what you mean

Comment: if we put `https://domain.dom/freddy_user` in address bar, then it will not go to index.html to run the above snippet

Comment: I have no idea how your server works. You were the one giving very little info on how you pass the userid. I just came up with something to not confuse userid=userid - it seems you need to play with htaccess instead of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you need the current URL and params, this could help you

I'am considering that the userID param is the first param like:

```
url.com/123
```

where 123 is the userID

```js
//Get current base URL
let base_url = window.location.origin;

//Get userID or first param
//Change number 3 if your param is in another position
let userId = window.location.href.split("/")[3];
alert(userId);

//Redirect to base URL
window.location.href = base_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by redirecting through the `.htaccess` file and further

`var path = location.pathname; var arr  = path.split("/"); var name = arr[arr.length-1];`

Hence, with this, we can achieve the parameters through the domain path in javascript.